How to serialize a single json field from two reverse foreign key relationships in Django REST Framework?
What I need
I'd like to get a single json field in the API response which lists identifiers for related objects based on two reverse foreign key relationships. Simple example what I mean by that is presented below. I'd highly prefer it to be handled on the Django REST Framework serializer level rather than having to change the model in some way, but I have very little DRF experience and I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually do it.
Example models.py:
class Person(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    father = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="children_as_father",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    mother = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        related_name="children_as_mother",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

Example database data:



id
first_name
last_name
mother
father




1
Jane
Smith




2
John
Smith




3
Clarence
Smith
1
2


4
Thomas
Smith
1
2



Example serialized json I would like to get:
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": null,
        "father": null,
        "children": [
            3,4
        ],
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": null,
        "father": null,
        "children": [
            3,4
        ],
    },
    {
        "pk": 3,
        "first_name": "Clarence",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": 1,
        "father": 2,
        "children": [],
    },
    {
        "pk": 4,
        "first_name": "Thomas",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": 1,
        "father": 2,
        "children": [],
    }
]


What I tried
That's as far as my experiments managed to get:
serializers.py
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, PrimaryKeyRelatedField
from .models import Person

class FamilySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    children_as_mother = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True, allow_null=True
    )

    children_as_father = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True, allow_null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [
            "pk",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "mother",
            "father",
            "children_as_mother",
            "children_as_father",
        ]

views.py
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .models import Person
from .serializers import FamilySerializer

class FamilyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint with family data
    """

    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

Serialized json:
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": null,
        "father": null,
        "children_as_mother": [
            3,4
        ],
        "children_as_father": [],
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": null,
        "father": null,
        "children_as_mother": [],
        "children_as_father": [
            3,4
        ],
    },
    {
        "pk": 3,
        "first_name": "Clarence",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": 1,
        "father": 2,
        "children_as_mother": [],
        "children_as_father": [],
    },
    {
        "pk": 4,
        "first_name": "Thomas",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "mother": 1,
        "father": 2,
        "children_as_mother": [],
        "children_as_father": [],
    }
]


As you can see compared to the first json example, it's not quite what I want - I'd like a single json field for listing a person's children identifiers ("children") and not two ("children_as_mother", "children_as_father").

Can you clarify what exactly your desired result is? As is, your first example says "this is what I want", and then you give another example where you say that the first example wasn't quite what you wanted. And finally, you mention having the children in a single JSON object, but your final example shows two JSON objects?

The first json is what I want to get, the second is what I managed to get so far.

@Vegard - I edited the question, I hope it's now more clear to read

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'mother', 'father', 'children']

    def get_children(self, obj):
        # Get all children of the demo
        children_as_father = obj.children_as_father.values_list('id', flat=True)
        children_as_mother = obj.children_as_mother.values_list('id', flat=True)
        return list(children_as_father) + list(children_as_mother)


https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

I managed to find an acceptable solution. Here's how I modified the serializer by overriding the to_representation function:
class FamilySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    children_as_mother = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True, allow_null=True
    )

    children_as_father = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True, allow_null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [
            "pk",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "mother",
            "father",
            "children_as_mother",
            "children_as_father",
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(FamilySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data["children"] = data["children_as_father"]+data["children_as_mother"]
        del data["children_as_mother"]
        del data["children_as_father"]        
        return data     

Alternatively to_representation can also be overriden like so to get the same effect for my specific dataset:
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(FamilySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        if data["children_as_father"]:
            data["children"] = data["children_as_father"]
        elif data["children_as_mother"]:
            data["children"] = data["children_as_mother"]
        else:
            data["children"]=[]
        del data["children_as_mother"]
        del data["children_as_father"]        
        return data

I'm leaving the question up for a few days in case anybody has another solution in mind, after that I'll mark this as the correct answer.
